# Eclipse+svn can't launch project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

If I add new repo in Eclipse and then check out, it appears in workspace, but I can't lauch it. Run configurations option is not enabled for this project. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to facet, I suspect these two cases.

- Verify if you checked out at right level. may be that you checked out sub directory of project. look for .project file.
- Verify android plugin is installed (assuming you are checking out android project).

Comment: As a best practice, do not commit your `.project` or `.settings` files. This is really important when you are working in a team setting.

Comment: @bhagyas thanks for info, any reference or decision driver would be appreciated.

Comment: An example case would be if your developers use different versions of eclipse with varied plugin configurations. The information is based on experience. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add project facets to your project depending on the technology or the run configuration you have used to enable launch configurations in eclipse.

For an example, see the link below.

http://www.beilers.com/2009/05/eclipse-project-facets/

Cheers!!!